# Apache rewrite - Redirects to example.com// instead of example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, 301-redirect

When trying to redirect an URL in apache from:

```
www.example.com
```

to

```
example.com
```

it redirects to

```
example.com//
```

This is a one page webserver, Fixed IP goes directly to the page.

Editing directly on httpd.conf

Any idea of why is this happening?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in a `.htaccess` file or a `<Directory />` block?  My guess is that it is not.

Inside those two areas, the URI path is matched to a full filesystem path and the the part that matches the directory, including the slash, is removed.

Outside one of these areas, the URI path starts with a slash.  Hence, your redirect puts an extra slash in.

You can change the rewrite rule to either:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

Or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

Comment: it is in httpd.conf file, I'm editing the file directly with vim. The first one worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Where is that rule configured?

Seems like it's probably in the server or virtualhost configuration, where it would have a leading slash in the match string, which is being captured and replaced into the redirect string.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

It doesn't seem like you need to be using mod_rewrite for this, if that's all the complexity you need.  If your rules don't need to be any more complex than this, use `Redirect` instead:

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
```

Comment: the first one worked. please expand the redirect part, added the line t o httpd.conf and it did not work.

Comment: @jacktrades Are you using virtual hosts, or just the main server config?  Did you remove the mod_rewrite config when you added the `Redirect` config?  What occurred when you tried to access a page with it configured?

Comment: main server config, yes I removed the mod_rewrite configs. I got: "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Answer (score 1):

How about change the line `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

Comment: yes, that worked. refreshed the browser and it's working fine now.